# How to express these vectors in terms of other given vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I have been searching the internet for these but I have been unable to find any exercise similar to them, I have managed to answer them but I don't know if I am right. Can anyone help?

The question:

Let the vectors $\vec p = 3\vec a - \vec b$ and $\vec q = \vec a + 2\vec b$ be given.

a) Find $3\vec p - 2\vec q$ in terms of $\vec a$ and $\vec b$.

b) Express $\vec b$ in terms of $\vec p$ and $\vec q$.

I have managed to answer them in this way:

a) 7$\vec a$ - 7$\vec b$

b) $\vec p$ - 3$\vec q$ / -7

Are my answers correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your answers are correct.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it.

Comment: That is not an acceptable answer.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos well that's all I asked